# Generar Array de dos dimensiones para tabla de conversión

Tags: javascript, array

quisiera declarar un array de dos dimensiones vacío y luego llenarlo de la siguiente manera para generar una tabla de conversión en JavaScript:

```
function ManagerVars(){
    var conv = [[],[]];
    conv['Lb']['Kg'] = 0.4536;
    conv['Oz']['Kg'] = 0.0284;
    conv['Kg']['Kg'] = 1;
    conv['Gr']['Kg'] = 0.001;
    return conv;
}
```

Pero me da error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'Kg' of undefined

---

He conseguido que me funcione de esta manera:

```
function ManagerVars(){
    //Objeto ccon datos de conversion: acceso
    //acceso: conv[indice]['Kg'] convertir de un indice a Kilogranmos
    //tambien se puede: conv.Lb.Kg
    var conv = {
        'Lb' : {'Kg' : 0.4536},
        'Oz' : {'Kg' : 0.0284},
        'Kg' : {'Kg' : 1},
        'Gr' : {'Kg' : 0.001}
    };
    return conv;
}
```

pero no me permite accesar al valor del objeto:

```
//console.log(conv.[med].Kg);
```

Donde `med` contiene: `'Lb'`

Resuelto y correccion(el punto estaba de mas):

```
var test = conv[med].Kg;
```

Comment: veo que resolviste el tema. En tal caso, añade una respuesta en lugar de editar la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hacelo de esta forma:

```
function ManagerVars(){
    var conv = {
    'Lb' : {'Kg' :0.4536},
    'Oz' : {'Kg' :0.0284},
    'Kg' : {'Kg' : 1},
    'Gr' : {'Kg' : 0.001}
    }
    return conv;
}
```

Comment: gracias probare esta opción.

Comment: ya listo estaba haciéndolo mal mezclando un array con un objeto y era objeto del objeto ...

Comment: me ayudaria con algo necesito tener acceso al dato mas o menos de esta manera: `console.log(conv.[med].Kg);`  donde `med` es una variable con el texto de indice de comversion `'Kg'`;

Comment: Seria conv['Kg'] o conv.Kg o no te entendí..

Comment: ok por ejemeplo si voy de Kg a Kg como acceder a conv.Kg.Kg en el caso de que tengo el primer indice 'Kg' guardado en una variable tipo med='Kg'

Comment: var med='Kg'; conv[med].Lb; por ejemplo.

Comment: Listo ya actualice el post y gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para resolverlo, yo usaría un objeto y claves de la siguente manera:

```js
function ManagerVars(){
    var conv = {
      'Lb>Kg':0.4536,
      'Oz>Kg':0.0284,
      'Kg>Kg':1,
      'Gr>Kg':0.001,
    };
    return conv;
}

// Obtener la tabla de conversión
var tablaConv = ManagerVars();
console.log(tablaConv);

// Obtener de Libras a Kilogramos
console.log(tablaConv['Lb>Kg']);

// Verificación de existencia de conversión:
var de = 'Lb';
var a = 'Lb';
if(typeof(tablaConv[de+'>'+a])==='undefined'){
  console.log('No existe conversión de ' + de + ' a ' + a);
} else {
  console.log('Sí existe conversión de ' + de + ' a ' + a + ' y vale ' + tablaConv[de+'>'+a]);
}
```

Comment: gracias amigo pero las claves deben estar separadas por eso es que se requiere de una manera bidimencional: me permitiria checar si la conversion no esta definida: `if(conv[med]['Kg']==undefined)`

Comment: de igual manera puedes verificarlo usando `if(typeof(conv[med] + '>Kg')===undefined)`. Una recomendación: usa `typeof` y `=== ` cuando compares con `undefined`

Comment: mucho código la idea es hacerlo lo mas simple...

Comment: Rectifico mi comentario anterior, olvidé las comillas alrededor de `undefined`: `if(typeof(conv[med] + '>Kg')==="undefined")`. Te recomiendo que uses `typeof` aunque sea mayor cantidad de código, si verificas que una variable no ha sido declarada usando `if(variableNoDeclarada == undefined)` obtendrás un error de referencia.